# How to use SSRS solution through TFS

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, sql-server-2012, ssdt-bi

I am using SQL server 2012. I have created one SSRS solution in SSDT (Sql sever data tools).
I want to add it in TFS Visual Studio 2010. It only used for Syncing purpose for all team members. so every one can get all reports by doing get latest every day. there is about 300 reports for different modules. I want to use SSRS solution through TFS.
previous project i was facing problem about Syncing of all my team members. because individual is created their own solutions and after completing report they are upload it on report server.

I don't want to do it again.

I want to use TFS to Syncing all teams members for all reports.

Any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

TFS will allow your team members to sync the reports locally to their machines whenever a change occurs or a report is added. Your team members will just need to get latest from TFS to their local workspace.

Sounds like you need to create a process for your team to follow and educate them on how reports should be added or modified.

For example, if you have a folder called reports in TFS then anytime a developer needs to make a change or add a report they would add it to this solution and folder. Lock down the ability to deploy reports straight to the server until approved therefore developers cannot bypass TFS.

Steps a developer would take to ensure the latest report is being updated or changed:

- Developer pulls down latest report folder from TFS locally
- Developer makes updates and changes
- Before developer checks in any changes they again pull down the latest to ensure they will not overwrite any new changes. A possible merge may be required if the report has changed since the developer started working on it.
- Developer checks in changes to TFS
- Once changes to reports are approved then the report is deployed to reporting server. This could be done via a TFS build.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if I misunderstood your question or problem.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you going to need to make a custom plugin that can sync your reports to other teams when it is checked in